# How to change SELECTOR from div element to class

Tags: imacros

Element have id=":h.f" and class="df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable"
i need to replace  DIV element with class, how can i correctly do it?

```
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#\\:h\\.f" CHARS="text"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="div[class=\"df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable\"]" CHARS="text"
```

Comment: now i have an error SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified, line 11 (Error code: -1001). Here is code      macros +="EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=\"div[class=\"df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable\"]\" CHARS={{!COL1}}" + "\n";

Comment: Here is how your code must look like: `macros += 'EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="div[class=\"df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable\"]" CHARS={{!COL1}}' + "\n";` .

Comment: anyway getting same error SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified, line 11 (Error code: -1001)

Comment: Sure. Simply double the backslashes and it'll be OK.